# SQL receive row and execute other query

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

I need a sql function to calculate data from different tables.

There are two tables,

```
tbl_moving
|-----------------------------|
| start_datetime      | value |
|-----------------------------|
| 2016-10-05 10:00:00 |   23  |
| 2016-10-05 10:10:00 |   24  |
|-----------------------------|

tbl_execution
|-----------------------------|
| executed_datetime   | value |
|-----------------------------|
| 2016-10-05 10:05:00 | true  |
| 2016-10-05 10:16:00 | false |
|-----------------------------|
```

Now I need to return a array with following data:

`"tbl_moving"."start_datetime",
 "tbl_moving"."value",
 "tbl_moving"."stop_datetime" (is the next start_datetime (10:10:00), 
 "tbl_execution"."value" (where executed_datetime is between "tbl_moving"."start_datetime" and the next start_datetime (10:10:00)`

My Problem is, I dont know how to receive a query result

Something like

```
a = SELECT max(start_datetime) as start_datetime FROM "tbl_moving" WHERE value != 0 ORDER BY sig_datetime DESC GROUP BY start_datetime LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function for that, you can do this with a single query:

```
select m.*, e.value
from (
  select m.start_datetime, 
         lead(m.start_datetime) over (order by m.start_datetime) as stop_datetime,
         m.value
  from tbl_moving m
) m 
   join tbl_execution e
     on e.start_datetime between m.start_datetime and m.stop_datetime
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :-)

Yesterday the query to build the complete object for 4000 rows, executed ~30 seconds.
Now with your line `lead(m.start_datetime) over (order by m.start_datetime) as stop_datetime,`
I Build only one query, with a execution time of >700ms.
(There are a lot more joins and subquerys then in the example above)